# XCode UI Testing swizzle API class methods

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

I have a simple app with two buttons that calls a JSON web service and prints out the result message.

I wanted to try the new XCode 7 UI Testing but I can't understand how to mock the API requests.

For simplicity I've built an example without actual requests nor any async operations.

I have the `ZZSomeAPI.swift` file in the main target:

```
import Foundation
public class ZZSomeAPI: NSObject {
  public class func call(parameter:String) -> Bool {
      return true
  }
}
```

Then my `ZZSomeClientViewController.swift`:

```
import UIKit
class ZZSomeClientViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func buttonClick(sender: AnyObject) {
        print(ZZSomeAPI.call("A"))
    }
}
```

Now I've added a UITest target, recorded tapping the button and I have something like:

```
import XCTest
class ZZSomeClientUITests: XCTestCase {
    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        continueAfterFailure = false
        XCUIApplication().launch()
    }

    func testCall() {
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.childrenMatchingType(.Window).elementBoundByIndex(0).childrenMatchingType(.Other).element.childrenMatchingType(.Other).elementBoundByIndex(1).childrenMatchingType(.Button).elementBoundByIndex(0).tap()
    }        
}
```

So this works and running the test will print out `true`. But I want to include a test when the API returns `false` without messing the API. So, I added `ZZSomeAPI.swift`to UI Tests target and tried method swizzling (UITest code updated):

```
import XCTest

class ZZSomeClientUITests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        continueAfterFailure = false
        XCUIApplication().launch()
    }

    func testSwizzle() {
        XCTAssert(ZZSomeAPI.call("a"))
        XCTAssertFalse(ZZSomeAPI.callMock("a"))
        XCTAssert(ZZSomeAPI.swizzleClass("call", withSelector: "callMock", forClass: ZZSomeAPI.self))
        XCTAssertFalse(ZZSomeAPI.call("a"), "failed swizzle")
    }

    func testCall() {
        XCTAssert(ZZSomeAPI.swizzleClass("call", withSelector: "callMock", forClass: ZZSomeAPI.self))
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.childrenMatchingType(.Window).elementBoundByIndex(0).childrenMatchingType(.Other).element.childrenMatchingType(.Other).elementBoundByIndex(1).childrenMatchingType(.Button).elementBoundByIndex(0).tap()
    }

}

extension NSObject {
    public class func swizzleClass(origSelector: String!, withSelector: String!, forClass:AnyClass!) -> Bool {
        var originalMethod: Method?
        var swizzledMethod: Method?

        originalMethod = class_getClassMethod(forClass, Selector(origSelector))
        swizzledMethod = class_getClassMethod(forClass, Selector(withSelector))

        if (originalMethod == COpaquePointer(bitPattern: 0)) { return false }
        if (swizzledMethod == COpaquePointer(bitPattern: 0)) { return false }

        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod!, swizzledMethod!)
        return true
    }
}

extension ZZSomeAPI {
    public class func callMock(parameter:String) -> Bool {
      return false
    }
}
```

So, `testSwizzle()` passes which means swizzling worked. But `testCall()` still prints `true` instead of `false`.
Is it because the swizzling is only done on the test target when UITest and main target are two different applications?
Is there any way around this?

I've found [Mock API Requests Xcode 7 Swift Automated UI Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33011896/mock-api-requests-xcode-7-swift-automated-ui-testing) but I'm not sure how to use `launchArguments` here.
In the example there's only one case, but I need to mock the `call()` method for different results for different test methods... If I use a `launchArgument` such as `MOCK_API_RESPONSE` containing the full response to be returned, the main target app delegate will have some "ugly test-only" code... Is there any way to check (in the main target) that it is being compiled for a UITest target so it only includes that code for that mocking launchArguments?

The cleanest option would be indeed to get swizzling to work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Xcode UI tests execute in a separate application from your application. So changes to classes in the test runner application will not affect the classes in the tested application.

This is different from a unit test, where your tests run inside your application process.

Comment: any hints on how to cleanly use launchArguments without affecting the code in the public release? Something like objC #IFDEF TESTENV if launchArgument... #ENDIF

Comment: and thanks for the confirmation, maybe I'll just fall back to unit testing instead of UI though it would be nice to be able to test the UI without calling the remote API (which I do not control)

Answer (score 2):

I've accepted Mats answer as the actual question (swizzling in UI testing) was answered.

But the current solution I ended up with was using an online mock server, http://mocky.io/, as the swizzling goal was to mock remote API calls.

Updated `ZZSomeAPI.swift` with a `public` property for the API URL instead of getting it inside the method:

```
import Foundation
public class ZZSomeAPI {
  public static var apiURL: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["API_URL"] as! String

  public class func call(parameter:String) -> Bool {
      ... use apiURL ...
  }
}
```

Then updated app delegate to make use of `launchArguments`

```
import UIKit
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        if NSProcessInfo().arguments.contains("MOCK_API") { // for UI Testing
            if let param = NSProcessInfo().environment["MOCK_API_URL"] {
                ZZSomeAPI.apiURL = param
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Then created `setupAPIMockWith` in my UI test case class to create mock responses in mocky.io on-demand:

```
import XCTest
class ZZSomeClientUITests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        continueAfterFailure = false
    }

    func setupAPIMockWith(jsonBody: NSDictionary) -> String {
        let expectation = self.expectationWithDescription("mock request setup")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.mocky.io/")!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        var theJSONText: NSString?
        do {
            let theJSONData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonBody, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
            theJSONText = NSString(data: theJSONData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        } catch {
            XCTFail("failed to serialize json body for mock setup")
        }

        let params = [
            "statuscode": "200",
            "location": "",
            "contenttype": "application/json",
            "charset": "UTF-8",
            "body": theJSONText!
        ]
        let body = params.map({
            let key = $0.0.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
            let value = $0.1.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
            return "\(key!)=\(value!)"
        }).joinWithSeparator("&")
        request.HTTPBody = body.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        var url: String?

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in

            XCTAssertNil(error)

            do {
                let json: NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary
                XCTAssertNotNil(json["url"])
                url = json["url"] as? String
            } catch {
                XCTFail("failed to parse mock setup json")
            }

            expectation.fulfill()
        }

        task.resume()

        self.waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5, handler: nil)
        XCTAssertNotEqual(url, "")

        return url!
    }

    func testCall() {
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launchArguments.append("MOCK_API")
        app.launchEnvironment = [
            "MOCK_API_URL": self.setupAPIMockWith([
                    "msg": [
                        "code": -99,
                        "text": "yoyo"
                    ]
                ])
        ]
        app.launch()

        app.childrenMatchingType(.Window).elementBoundByIndex(0).childrenMatchingType(.Other).element.childrenMatchingType(.Other).elementBoundByIndex(1).childrenMatchingType(.Button).elementBoundByIndex(0).tap()
        app.staticTexts["yoyo"].tap()
    }

}
```